# Clienterror: An error occured when calling the CreateModel operation

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker

I want to deploy sklearn model in sagemaker. I created a training script.

scripPath=' sklearn.py'

`sklearn=SKLearn(entry_point=scripPath,
                                 train_instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
                                   role=role,                  output_path='s3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket,prefix), sagemaker_session=session)
sklearn.fit({"train-dir' : train_input})`

When I deploy it
`predictor=sklearn.deploy(initial_count=1,instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge')`

It throws,
`Clienterror: An error occured when calling the CreateModel operation:Could not find model data at s3://tree/sklearn/output/model.tar.gz`

Can anyone say how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying models, SageMaker looks up S3 to find your trained model artifact. It seems that there is no trained model artifact at `s3://tree/sklearn/output/model.tar.gz`. Make sure to persist your model artifact in your training script at the appropriate local location in docker which is `/opt/ml/model`.
for example, in your training script this could look like:

```
joblib.dump(model, /opt/ml/model/mymodel.joblib)
```

After training, SageMaker will copy the content of `/opt/ml/model` to s3 at the `output_path` location.

If you deploy in the same session a `model.deploy()` will map automatically to the artifact path. If you want to deploy a model that you trained elsewhere, possibly during a different session or in a different hardware, you need to explicitly instantiate a model before deploying

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.model import SKLearnModel

model = SKLearnModel(
    model_data='s3://...model.tar.gz',  # your artifact
    role=get_execution_role(),
    entry_point='script.py')  # script containing inference functions

model.deploy(
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
    initial_instance_count=1,
    endpoint_name='your_endpoint_name')
```

See more about Sklearn in SageMaker here https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_sklearn.html

Comment: Thanks for the response..what is the path given in model_data??

Comment: this is the artifact of the model in s3, it is the same path as output_path used when you train the model